# Saving data using where clause

Tags: cakephp, orm, save, associations, cakephp-3.0

I would like to be able to save data while providing a where clause.

I have the following code:

```
$game = $this->Games->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $game = $this->Games->patchEntity($game, $this->request->data);
    if ($this->Games->save($game)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The game has been saved.'));

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The game could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$this->Games->save($game)->innerJoinWith('Leagues', function ($q) use($s) {
                    return $q->where(['Leagues.user_id' => $s]);
                }
            )
```

I suspect having to do a find with a where clause and patch the request data to it?

```
$game = $this->Games->find()->innerJoinWith('Leagues', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['Leagues.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
})
->where(['Games.id' => $id])
->first();

if(! count($game)){
    $this->Flash->error(__('The game could not be found.'));
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}

if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $game = $this->Games->patchEntity($game, $this->request->data);
    if ($this->Games->save($game)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The game has been saved.'));

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The game could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

Anything simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such saving syntax, retrieving the proper entity in beforehand is the correct way to go, and there isn't really a "simpler" way - however there surely is room for optimization.

Personally I'd use finders to [**DRY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) things up, ie create a finder on the `GamesTable` that restricts things to specific league users:

```
public function findForLeagueUser(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    if (!isset($options['id'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The `id` option is invalid or missing.');
    }

    return $query
        ->innerJoinWith('Leagues', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) use ($options) {
            return $query->where([
                $this->Leagues->aliasField('user_id') => $options['id']
            ]);
        });
}
```

and combine things in the controller action:

```
$game = $this->Games
    ->find('forLeagueUser', ['id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
    ->where(['Games.id' => $id])
    ->first();
```

You could also use `firstOrFail()` instead, which throws an exception if the record cannot be found, this is what `Table::get()` does internally too.

And you could reduce things even further by using a dynamic finder for the games id:

```
$game = $this->Games
    ->findById($id)
    ->find('forLeagueUser', ['id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
    ->first();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & ... > Using Finders to Load Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & ... > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Dynamic Finders](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#dynamic-finders)**
- **[API > \Cake\Datasource\QueryTrait::firstOrFail()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Datasource.QueryTrait.html#_firstOrFail)**

Comment: Thanks for the insight!